# Neat / Borbon boxes with the wrong border

Tags: html, css, bourbon, neat

i try to put all red boxes in the yellow outline and start a new set of fields in the blue outline. I dont understand why only the h3 tag is in the yellow box but the red boxes in the blue outline.

http://sassmeister.com/gist/573fd05bac6b393e7640

Comment: Your red elements are floated. Floated elements are taken out of the flow (which means the parent won't expand to fit their height). You'll need to use a clearfix: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

Comment: Thanks this solves the problem but i think this is not the best way to make the grid working